# Algorithmic problem represented by a graph

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have N football teams. For each team, I know the opponents that can beat her (# of opponents can be 0). If I can 'fix' the matches (arrange them myself) I need to see for how many teams I can fix a winning result.

For example, let's say I have 5 teams. Input:

```
5
1 5 (team 1 loses from 1 opponent->5)
3 1 4 5(team 2 loses from 3 opponents->1,4,5)
2 1 4(team 3 loses from 2 opponents->1,4)
1 1
1 3
```

Output: 4 (I can fix the result for 1,3,4,5)
If I want, for example, 1 to win, matches must be:

1. 5-3 => winner=3
2. 4-1 => winner=1
3. 3-1 => winner=1
4. 2-1 => winner=1

I thought about creating a directed graph where edge (u,v) from u to v means that team u loses from team v.  If  the matches are played sequentialy in the finals team v (assume we want v to win) must play with a team belonging in a u to v vertex(u loses to v).  So team u either jumps straight to the finals or plays a pre-finals match where she wins using the same logic.  What i would like to ask is this: What should we do when there are multiple (u,v) edges (v being the team we want to win)?  After finding a team that loses to v, I get stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Bid you mistype the input for teams 2 and 3? Should it be `3 1 4 5 (team 3 loses...)` and `2 1 4 (team 2 loses...)`? Also, what about the last two lines? Does `1 1` mean "team 1 loses against team 1`?

Comment: Also, how are the "brackets" for 5 (or generally n) teams?

Comment: Please delete your [previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814911/how-can-i-build-a-graph-to-represent-my-data-in-this-situation) of this question.

Comment: I feel that you still need to research basic graph algorithms.  You have a directed graph.  For each node, you need to determine whether there exists a spanning tree with that node as the root.  The case you're worried about is solved with existing traversal algorithms, using BFS or DFS (breadth-first or depth-first search).  Also look for the term "backtracking".  Briefly, you follow each track in turn until you find one that works for you.  If you run out of possibilities, then there is no way to make that team the champion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *loser tree* of a single-elimination tournament is a tree where the winner is the root and the parent of each other node is the node it lost to. As Prune notes, you can fix a tournament for a particular node if and only if there exists a loser tree where that node is the root and each loser->winner arc appears in the graph. The "only if" direction is obvious; the "if" direction follows by scheduling the matches in the order of a post-order traversal.

Taking this logic one step further, there exists such a tree if and only if there is a directed path from the winner to each other node. The "only if" direction is obvious (just extract the path in the tree); the "if" direction follows, as Prune notes, from depth-first or breadth-first search.

The reachability structure of the graph is summarized by its [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component). Tarjan gave a linear-time algorithm to label each node with its strongly connected component. Given these labels, you're looking for exactly one strongly connected component in which no node has an outgoing arc to any other component. Everyone in this component can be a winner, and no one else can. If there are two or more such components, then (a) I guess it's possible to draw a tournament match (b) there are no possible winners.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution!